# How does reddit's login validate credentials without reloading the page?

Tags: forms, validation, authentication, reddit

When you enter your credentials on reddit login page, it first checks their validity and if they're valid only then it redirects, otherwise the fields are updated with a "wrong password" message.

I'm trying to understand how the submit button validates the credential without actually submitting the form, and thus, reloading the page.

[image]

Comment: too broad? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228520/my-question-is-too-broad

Comment: (reason for close vote) I understand your problem ("I'm trying to understand..."), but it is not clear _what you are asking_. Straight-up "how does it work" is just too broad. But that has been discussed in the meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Ajax: Asynchronious javascript and XML.

The purpose of ajax is exactly what you said. Google ajax for more info.

Comment: You can also look at the network request in chrome developer tools / network tab to see what they're sending.